# Selecting all rows with the first 5 different values of a list

Tags: python, numpy, cluster-analysis

I have a predefined list with 100 elements, whose values represent cluster labels.
First, I would like to find the first 5 different cluster labels from the list.
Then, I want to select all rows that have one of the five values as entry, and finally write their index and label into a new array.

How do I have to adjust my code to achive that?
I think I have to use a loop, but since I am new to python I dont know how to set it correctly.

```
list = np.array(list)

new_array = []
for x in list:
  new_array.append(list[index, value]) 
print(new_array)
```

Comment: Will you please provide a sample of your array? Also, a sample of your expected output?

Comment: sample:
list= [0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 4, 4, 1, 6, 3, 1, 3, 2, 3, 7]
the first different 5 values are 0, 1, 2, 3, 5 0
structure of new array: 1.st colum row indexes , 2. column (value of corresponding row 
new array = [0,0], [1,0], [2,1], [3,0], [4,2], [5,1], [6,3], [7,5], [12,1], [14,3], [15,1] [16,3], [17,2], [18,3]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `np.unique` to get the unique values of a list:

```
first_vals = np.unique(list)[:5]

new_array = []
for index, value in enumerate(list):
    if value in first_vals:
        new_array.append([index, value])
print(new_array)
```

Output:

```
[[0, 0], [1, 0], [2, 1], [3, 0], [4, 2], [5, 1], [6, 3], [10, 4], [11, 4], [12, 1], [14, 3], [15, 1], [16, 3], [17, 2], [18, 3]]
```

(Note: it's bad practice use names of Python builtins as variable names, e.g. `list`